# Finite groups of the form p^3q

Tags: finite-groups

Hi,

Is there any way to classify finite non-abelian groups of order p^3q with p and q primes?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, either a Sylow p-group is normal or a Sylow q-group is normal, unless your group has order 24.

Comment: And even in the order 24 case, $S_4$ is the only exception.

Comment: This is indeed a well known fact. In case you want a reference, I can strongly recommend Martin Isaac's book "Finite Group Theory". The theorem that Steve mentioned is in Theorems 1.32 and 1.33 of that book.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like a historical reference, Burnside in his book cites Western, "Groups of order $p^3q$", Proc. LMS Vol xxx. 1899 pp. 209--263,  But the length of that paper suggests another source would be better if all you want is the result...